# Find center line to given list of (sympy) lines

Tags: math, line, center, sympy

I am currently struggling with the current problem:
I have defined *n* lines (with SymPy). In the end, they shall describe a polygon. (See target in image)

Now I want to find the "mid" or "center" line to those polygons. 
My first thought was to put a circle between the lines. 
But: How does the algorithm know which lines are the opposing ones to put the "ball" between?

So basically I can define a line to start. Now I am searching for the line with the nearest distance and so on. But this solution does not seem generic enough to me to able to capture all polygon types.

How can I write my script so that it is able to create a polygon center line(or lines in example case e) ) from a list of sympy lines?

I also ready something about "skeletonization", but this seems to be more suited for pixel images.

Thanks a lot!
Best regards
Benny

[Example cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4hnH.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. You write of "lines" but your example `c)` does not have lines but rather "polylines" or something similar. You write of "a set of lines" but show and then write of only two lines. I do not understand what you mean by "the opposing line to the current line." Please clarify.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am still not sure how to describe it properly but I hope that my problem is now clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how general your solution must be, but here's a technique that should work to find the mid line for the three use-cases in the link:

Assume one blue line is defined by the points (B1, B2) and the other blue line is defined by points (D1, D2). I would create two new lines: one connecting B1 and D1, and the other connecting B2 and D2. Using SymPy it should be easy to determine the midpoint of a line segment. The desired red line would be the line connecting the midpoint of the (B1, D1) segment and the (B2, D2) segment.

This should work without modifications for (a) and (b); the (c) case can be solved with the same idea, if you remember to handle each pair of line segments separately. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Descartes, thank you for your answer. This approach was also my first thought, but already if the lines are not similar anymore (e.g. x/y coordinates), this will get more complicated. This approach is useful, if the user knows which lines to connect. But since I want to do it in an automated way: How does the script know which lines to connect or use for the mid-line calculation ? (Especially if there are >4 lines)

Comment: When you say >4 lines, do you mean that each of the two blue lines (the lines to find the middle line for) could have at least 5 segments? Or do you mean that there could be 5+ blue lines, to find the middle line of all of them (similar to a regression line)? 
If there are only ever 2 blue lines with an arbitrary number of segments, it shouldn't be hard to assign a "start" and "end" (assuming each blue line is continuous). Once you pick a start and end for each segment, I believe you can determine which start/end to connect. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think I cannot follow you completely right now, perhaps my brain has had enough today. But have you taken a look at the "target", case d) and e) in my uploaded (and updated) image? These are perhaps describing the problem better. In example case d): How does the script realize where to put the center line in between? Which lines to consider for the center line evaluation? Especially in the asymmetric transition area from trapezoid to simple rectangle. I am imagining a ball rolling through (with adapting radius)

Comment: @BennyS Are you sure that the red line is correct in d) ?

Comment: The examples do not have to be completely correct since I only sketched the red line in the examples using powerpoint. The start of the "non-horizontal" line should be a little bit more to the right for example.

Comment: @BennyS I got a different solution line for d) . Based on my understanding, the solution line should only have two segments? Please see https://ibb.co/fLMgUo (sorry it is rotated)

Comment: Hi @Descartes , unfortunately, my issue is not resolved so far. I have some other work to do at the moment, thats why the priority for this issue decreased at the moment. On the weekend I had some time to put some effort in again but I did not come to a solution. As soon as I have an idea, i will explain that in this thread.

Comment: Could you explain why my proposed solution is not correct? It would help to resolve your issue

Comment: I am looking for a solution that is completely generic. Your solution is right but it depends on knowledge which lines to use to build the geometric construct. However, I only want to give the polygon to the script, and due to smart algorithms it detects on its own how to build the maximum circles between the lines. At the current state, I found an approach that comes pretty close to my objective: It's called medial axis transformation.